# Substituir todos os argumentos (de todas as strings) que existem em um dict com .format

Tags: python, python-3.x

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira pythonica de substituir todos os argumentos (de todas as strings) que existem em dicionário com o .format .Por exemplo:

```
dicionario = {"nome": "{nome_usuario}", "idade": 26, "infos": [ {"nome": "{nome_usuario}" }]}
informacoes = {"nome_usuario": "Joao"}
```

Sem ter que fazer:

```
dicionario["nome"] = dicionario["nome"].format(**informacoes)
dicionario["infos"][0]["nome"] = dicionario["infos"][0]["nome"].format(**informacoes)
```

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira mais eficiente de fazer isso.

OBS: O dicionario seria um arquivo JSON

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se existir a possibilidade de alterar o formato, você pode utilizar a estrutura `Template` nativa da biblioteca `string` do Python. Por exemplo, ao invés de fazer os valores entre chaves, `{nome_usuario}`, você poderia colocar o prefixo `$`, `$nome_usuario`, e substituir os valores através do template.

```js
{
  "nome": "$nome_usuario", 
  "idade": 26, 
  "infos": [
    {
      "nome": "$nome_usuario"
    }
  ]
}
```

Assim, tendo os valores em um dicionário:

```py
informacoes = {"nome_usuario": "Joao"}
```

Basta você ler o arquivo e aplica o template:

```py
import string


informacoes = {"nome_usuario": "Joao"}

with open('data.json') as stream:
  content = stream.read()

template = string.Template(content)

print(template.substitute(**informacoes))
```

Com isso você terá a saída:

```js
{
  "nome": "João", 
  "idade": 26, 
  "infos": [
    {
      "nome": "João"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigada! Essa solução me atende perfeitamente.

Não conhecia essa estrutura Template, vou ler mais sobre ela.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode criar uma subclasse de dict, que tenha um parâmetro de substituição, e faça o `.format` diretamente no `__getitem__` - aí o próprio mecanismo do Python gera a formatação em cada string que você for usar, e você nem precisa ter um "ponto no programa onde você formata as strings" - elas simplesmente vão aparecer formatadas na substituição.  O interssante dessa abordagem é que se você trocar o conteúdo do dicionário "informações" - como é o mesmo objeto referenciado dentro do dicionário modificado, todas as novas leituras serão feitas com as novas informações.

Uma versão simples pode herdar de dict, fazer uma substuição recursiva na criação, tratando listas como um caso especial:

```py
class AutoFormatDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, original_dict, format_data):
        for key, value in original_dict.items():
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                original_dict[key] = AutoFormatDict(value, format_data)
            elif isinstance(value, list):
                for position, list_value in enumerate(value):
                    if isinstance(list_value, dict):
                        value[position] = AutoFormatDict(list_value, format_data)
        super().__init__(original_dict)
        self.format_data = format_data

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        value = super().__getitem__(key)
        return value.format(**self.format_data) if isinstance(value, str) else value
```

E no terminal, dados os dois dicionários que você apresenta na pergunta, funciona assim:

```py
In [24]: data = AutoFormatDict(dicionario, informacoes)                                    

In [25]: data["infos"][0]["nome"]                                                          
Out[25]: 'Joao'

In [26]: informacoes                                                                       
Out[26]: {'nome_usuario': 'Joao'}

In [27]: informacoes["nome_usuario"] = "Pedro"                                             

In [28]: data["infos"][0]["nome"]                                                          
Out[28]: 'Pedro'
```

## Versao sofisticada e "production ready"

Uma implementação um pouco mais sofisticada pode fazer a substituição recursiva só na leitura - dentro do "getitem" e pode herdar de "collections.abc.Sequence" em vez de "dict" - isso garante que a substituição vai funcionar para *todos* os métodos de leitura de um dicionário (iteração com "for", metodos "get", "setdefault", "pop" e etc...). Essa abordagem precisa de uma classe companheira especializando
a lista também - já que o método "getitem" da lista é separado.

Essa versão pode ser considerada "avançada" por que usa
as classes de "collections.abc" - mas é boa o suficiente
para ser colocada em código de produção em qualquer aplicação,
ou publicada numa biblioteca no Pypi.

(E, claro, ja que estamos sofisticando, podemos fazer uma outra classe auxiliar -- para não termos um erro nas strings que faltara na substituição)

Então, herdando de [`collections.abc.MutableMapping` e `collections.abc.MutableSequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html). Como a maior parte dos
métodos vai fazer a mesma coisa - simplesmente passar
os parâmetros recebidos para a estrutura "data" interna,
podemos refatorar isso para uma classe de base - 
e só precisamos implementar o `insert` e o `__iter__` 
separadamente.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
from collections.abc import MutableMapping, MutableSequence, Sequence, Mapping



class _AutoFormatMixin:
    def __init__(self, template_data, subst_data):
        self.data = template_data
        self.substitution = defaultdict(lambda: '', subst_data)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.data[key] = value

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del self.data[key]

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        value = self.data[key]
        if isinstance(value, Mapping):
            return AutoFormatDict(value, self.substitution)
        elif isinstance(value, str):
            return value.format_map(self.substitution)
        elif isinstance(value, Sequence) and not isinstance(value, (bytes, bytearray)):
            return AutoFormatList(value, self.substitution)
        return value

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}({self.data!r}, {self.substitution!r})"


class AutoFormatDict(_AutoFormatMixin, MutableMapping):
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.data)


class AutoFormatList(_AutoFormatMixin, MutableSequence):
    def insert(self, index, value):
        self.data.insert(index, value)
```

E funcionando:

```py
In [83]: data = AutoFormatDict(dicionario, informacoes)                                    

In [84]: data.substitution["nome_usuario"] = "Beatriz"                                     

In [85]: data["infos"][0]["nome"]                                                          
Out[85]: 'Beatriz'

In [86]: data.substitution["nome_usuario"] = "Bruno"                                       

In [87]: data["infos"][0]["nome"]                                                          
Out[87]: 'Bruno'
```

Comment: As duas soluções propostas por você são bem sofisticadas! Parabéns... elas me ajudaram também.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode implementar uma função recursiva capaz de percorrer todas as chaves e valores do dicionário em busca de valores que sejam do tipo `string` para só então aplicar a formatação, veja só:

```
def formatar_strings( d, info ):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            d[k] = formatar_strings(v, info)
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            d[k] = [formatar_strings(e, info) for e in v]
        elif isinstance(v, str):
            d[k] = d[k].format(**info)
    return d


dicionario = {"nome": "{nome_usuario}", "idade": 26, "infos": [ {"nome": "{nome_usuario}" }]}
informacoes = {"nome_usuario": "Joao"}
saida = formatar_strings( dicionario, informacoes );
print(saida)
```

Saída:

```
{'nome': 'Joao', 'idade': 26, 'infos': [{'nome': 'Joao'}]}
```

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/FrayedPaltryHypotenuse)